# CSS/SCSS: Elemento de validação genérico acompanhando o formato input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end, sass, flexbox

Estou com um problema em minha folha de estilo.

Eu possuo um Input genérico, conforme a figura abaixo:
[image: Inputs de validação genéricos]

Eu coloquei um elemento para validar o meu formulário, a validação esta OK, mas estou com problemas no alinhamento, pois se eu aumento ou diminuo o campo de texto, o elemento permanece.

Veja um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O elemento de validação permaneceu no mesmo lugar, mesmo eu aumentando o Input. eu gostaria que ele acompanhasse o input de acordo ao seu formato. Meu código esta da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="{{type}}" class="form-control" id="{{name}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [value]="value || ''  " (keyup)="capterField(fieldValue.value)"
    #fieldValue>
  <div class="circle-validation" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{messageError}}" [ngClass]="{ 'default': defaultValidation, 'success': isValid && isValid !== undefined, 'danger': !isValid && isValid !== undefined}">
  </div>
  <label for="{{name}}">{{label}}</label>
</div>
```

O meu SCSS que trata esse estado esta logo abaixo:

```
input.form-control {
  border: 1px solid $pink-color;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 45px 15px 30px 15px;
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid $primary-color;
  }
}

.circle-validation {
  content: '';
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  left: 300px;
  top: -45px;
  cursor: pointer;

  &.default {
    background-color: $default-light-color;
  }
  &.success {
    background-color: $success-color;
  }
  &.danger {
    background-color: $danger-color;
  }
}


label {
  font-size:  12.5px;
  opacity:  .8;
  font-weight:  400;
}

.input-container {
  position:  relative;
  margin-bottom:  10px;
  label {
    color: $blue-color;
    text: {
      transform: uppercase;
    }
    font-weight: 700;
    position:  absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 30px);
    left:  15px;
    opacity:  1;
    transition: all .3s ease;
  }
  input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    padding:  45px 15px 30px 15px;
  }
  input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
    transform:  translateY(0px);
    color: $primary-color;
    opacity:  .7;
  }
}
```

Grato pela contribuição desde já!

Comment: qual é a versão do bootstrap?

Comment: Versão 4 do bootstrap.

Comment: Outra coisa o CSS principal que seria da classe `.circle-validation` não está no código acima... seria bom que tivesse para poder te responder com precisão

Comment: Esta ali... eu havia realizado uma atualização....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente utilizar a classe pull-right na div de validação do bootstrap para ver ser resolve seu problema.

essa classe força o elemento sempre ir para a direita

Comment: Eu consegui aqui @Lucas Augusto. Adicionado o float Right e dentre outras propriedades básicas... Mas ainda estou em busca de uma solução que use o flex-box para melhorar o componente. mas vou editar a sua resposta.

Comment: você pode utilizar a propriedade **justify-content: flex-end** todos os elementos dentro da div pai no lado direito